# Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Hanged on Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS around one month ago as dual boot with Windows 8.1 and it was working excellent. But from yesterday it stopped working. Laptop hangs during Ubuntu boot in the Ubuntu logo screen.

After that I have searched for solution in askubuntu. But, nothing helped in my issue.

**Edit:** I have found that the reason was recent `dbus` installation. How can I install `dbus` without having similar problem again.

Comment: Do you have GPU on your laptop?

Comment: output of `lspci | grep VGA` is `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`. No extra graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue 2 days ago after an upgrade. I discovered that the issue comes from from 2 dpkg-bak files which were linking to the same file as their replacements. It seems it was disturbing for dbus.
The 2 files that I removed to fix the problem were:

- `/etc/dbus-1/session.conf.dpkg-bak`
- `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf.dpkg-bak`

PS: reinstallation of dbus had no effect, I had to solve it manually.